# Connect two VGA dell displays to my macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, vga-adapter

I want to buy two 17 inch dell displays to use them with my mackbook pro 13 inch with one thunderbolt port but I dont want to buy them until I know that I can use them haha

I want to know which adapter I have to buy (I live in mexico so it might be difficult) or if I can use the normal thunderbolt to vga that I have and this one: http://mlm-s2-p.mlstatic.com/cable-adaptador-convertidor-usb-a-vga-tarjeta-video-externa-14810-MLM20090514678_052014-O.jpg.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple displays with MacBook Pro. Retina version have two thunderbolt ports that you can use simultaneously to two external displays along with MacBook's LCD panel.

There are also USB cables which comes with internal display card attached, so it will not have the same speed the MacBook's integrated display card, but if it is compatible with your OS version, should work without any issues.